# The type or namespace name 'DbEntityEntry<TEntity>' could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following interface that I used before EF7. When I try to build the application using EF7, I receive the following error, and I cannot seem to find this type anywhere. I'd really appreciate your suggestions about how to change this code for EF7.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbEntityEntry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public interface IContext
{
    DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `DbEntityEntry` type within Entity Framework 7. The whole underlying change tracking implementation has changed and there is no exact replication of this.

There is a [`EntityEntry`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/ChangeTracking/EntityEntry%60.cs) type within the new `Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking` namespace which has a similar purpose but it works a bit differently as is not compatible to the [`DbEntityEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696410.aspx) type in earlier versions of Entity Framework.

You can access it from the [`ChangeTracker`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/ChangeTracking/ChangeTracker.cs#L92) which is accessible via `DbContext.ChangeTracker`.

But as for keeping that interface, this is unlikely to help you as quite a few things has changed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I am going to dig into EF7 docs to see what I need to revamp.  Have a great holiday, and thank you for your help!